# Phonegap-built app works on Android (Pixel 2) but not Kindle Fire?

Tags: phonegap-build, kindle-fire

I've gotten my app running on my Pixel 2 phone without any problems, and submitted it to the Google Play store. I wanted to put it on the Amazon App Store as well, but they sent me back the message, "We are unable to test your app due to install/launch failure in all compatible devices. Please fix the issue and re-submit the app."

So I thought I'd try to test it on a Kindle Fire (it's a Kids' Fire so it's probably running like Lollipop or something), but I can't seem to install it. I got the ADB bridge going and everything, but when I go to install the APK, it gives me the message, "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]". Older than what? Googling this error tells me to edit the manifest, but I can't do that since all I have is the apk file. Can I just get Phonegap build to give me an uncompiled apk and open it and edit it in Android Studio? I've written basic Android programs before, but this one seemed easier to do in HTML.

I'm not really sure where to start. Nothing I can think of Googling seems to help, and the Kindle information on the Phonegap website says not to use it because it's outdated, and then doesn't redirect me anywhere useful. It seems to be more related to Phonegap than Phonegap Build anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had, for reasons I cannot recall, set the minimum SDK version in the Phonegap Build config.xml file to "24". That obviously didn't work on Lollipop. I changed it to "14", which is the default, and added the preference for target SDK and put that at 24 just in case I had some kind of reason for doing that. It installs correctly on the Kindle now. Hopefully Amazon's store will no longer have issues.